# Add different images when mouse moving in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a jquery code where you can show different images (1-3 different images) when you move the mouse around.

The images will be right beside the cursor, and they will only appear 1-3, not more than that. And each time the mouse moves, these images will change.

I currently have this as my html code,

```
  <div class="mainbody">
    <section class="container">
      <div class="img_div">
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

And  my jquery code looks like this:

```
let img_array = ['./img/awards_icon.png', './img/norinuri_icon.png'];
  $("div.mainbody").mousemove(function(e) {
    for(i=0; i<img_array.length; i++){
      $('.img_div').append("<img src='" + img_array[i] +"'/>");
      $('.img_div').fadeIn("5000");
      $('.img_div').finish().fadeOut("5000");
      $('.img_div').offset({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY + 20
      });
    }
  });
```

The 2 images that I have in my jquery array appears when the mouse moves, but instead of only having 2 images these images add continuously, without stopping.
So each time I would move my mouse, the images would continue to add infinitely.

I will add more images in the jquery array for sure, 
but how should I have only two images added, and change these images as I move the mouse?

Comment: what is way to take 2/3 image? Currently you're appending to the `image_div` Instead empty and then append. and limit the loop to run 2 times.

Comment: r u trying to change background image each time your mouse move?

Comment: "each time I move my mouse" - put a `console.log("mousemove")` inside `.mousemove()` function (remove all the other code for now) - you'll see that mousemove fires 100s of times as you move the mouse, because it fires (more or less) for every pixel you move across.   You should add a single `<img>` and change it's `src` each time rather than add a new one.  You could also `debounce` the mousemove so that it doesn't fire as often.

Comment: @freedomn-m ah, you're right, I'll try to change the `src` each time rather than adding a new one!

Comment: @vijayP not necessarily the background image, but a image in a div that will follow everywhere the cursor goes

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-image`

```js
var imageArr=["https://www.w3schools.com/css/paper.gif","https://www.w3schools.com/css/gradient_bg.png","https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_tree.png"];
var count=0;
$( ".mainbody" ).mouseover(function() {
  $( ".img_div" ).css('background-image', 'url("' + imageArr[count] + '")');
  if(count == imageArr.length-1)
    count=0;
  else
   count++;
});
```

```css
.mainbody{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.img_div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainbody">
  <section class="container">
    <div class="img_div">
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

[Here is working fiddle;](https://jsfiddle.net/79fbjwkd/)

**USING `mousemove`** (to avoid the images to change so many times while mouse move I use `timeout`)

```js
var imageArr=["https://www.w3schools.com/css/paper.gif","https://www.w3schools.com/css/gradient_bg.png","https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_tree.png"];
var count=0;
var timeoutid = 0;

function setImage() {
  $( ".img_div" ).css('background-image', 'url("' + imageArr[count] + '")');
  if(count == imageArr.length-1)
    count=0;
  else
   count++;
}


$(".mainbody").mousemove(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutid);
    timeoutid = setTimeout(setImage, 100);
});
```

```css
.mainbody{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.img_div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainbody">
  <section class="container">
    <div class="img_div">
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

**화이팅!**

Comment: tell me for more help(도움을 더 알려주세요)

Comment: yeah this works, but I was searching for a way where the images will stay right beside the cursor.. then it wouldn't be able to set as a css background image,

Comment: Do you want something like this?https://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/SYwba/

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have created a working example for you. You can try it now:

```
<div class="mainbody">
<section class="container">
  <div class="img_div">
    hello
  </div>
</section>
```

**css**

```
.mainbody {
  border:1px solid red;
  display:block;
  height:1000px
}
```

**jquery**

```
let img_array = ['https://anotherjavaduke.files.wordpress.com/2018/08/avataaars-2.png', 
'https://images2.minutemediacdn.com/image/upload/c_crop,h_1192,w_2121,x_0,y_111/f_auto,q_auto,w_1100/v1554921884/shape/mentalfloss/22461-istock-176984635.jpg'];

$("div.mainbody").on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var i;
    $('.img_div').html('')

    for (i = 0; i < img_array.length; i++) {
        console.log($('.img_div').has('img').length)

        if ($('.img_div').has('img').length < img_array.length) {

            $('.img_div').append("<img style='width:100px; height:100px' src='" + img_array[i] + "'/>");
            $('.img_div').fadeIn("5000");
            $('.img_div').finish().fadeOut("5000");
            $('.img_div').offset({
                left: e.pageX,
                top: e.pageY + 20
            });


        }

    }
});
```

**Working example**
[Codepen] `https://codepen.io/prashen/pen/ZEEqJEo`

Comment: @So Heum Hwang You can check this out and let me know.

Comment: I see you've attempted to get around SO telling you not to post link only answers.  Do you think that restrictions there for fun? Or because the devs didn't know what they were doing?  Or just to be a pain?  Please don't try to bypass restrictions that are there for a reason.

Comment: Okay, Actually I have created a working example there. Okay then have to post here also.

Comment: @freedomn-m I have updated the answer. Should I remove the codepen link entirely?

Comment: The key is that, if every site on the internet went down except SO, questions and answers would still be readable/accessible.  Adding extra info (especially with lots of code to generate a working example) is fine when that site is static (as is codepen/jsfiddle).  FYI a link to a transient/temp site (not in the case) eg when someone is asking a question on a site they are currently working on that will change in minutes/days is completely useless.